# Phase of complex nonsinusoidal signals

Tags: phase, hilbert-transform

What's the best method for calculating phase of complex nonsinusoidal signals?

I've tried using Hilbert transform, but I've found that my results change drastically depending on the amount of data I pass through the Hilbert transform. What I'm seeing is that the phase angle calculated depends on the maximum amplitude of the original signal. I don't understand how to deal with this.

I have motion capture data - tracking one marker on a foot in 3D space. During one part of my experiment, the foot moves less and at a lower velocity. During another part of the experiment, the amplitude and velocity increase. If I calculate phase for all of my data (both parts of the experiment) I get completely different results than if I calculate phase for each part of the experiment separately. When calculating phase for the entire trial, phase fluctuations are TINY (hovering near +pi or near -pi) except for the time when the foot amplitude and velocity reach their overall maximum - at that time phase fluctuates between pi and -pi. The maximum velocity/amplitude is about 1.8 times greater than the average during the first part of the experiment, but there is still sizeable motion during the first part of the experiment. If I calculate phase for each part of the experiment separately, I get more normal looking phase results, fluctuating between +- pi .

I ultimately want to calculate synchronicity between two such signals. 
Can anyone explain this or provide advice?

Comment: Your signals are not a simple sinewave, so you need to define what you mean by "phase".  With reference to what?  (e.g. carefully describe a phase of zero.)

Comment: Many phase discriminators are sensitive to amplitude- can you provide more details on what you are doing specifically to measure the phase? If you are dealing with complex samples, each sample has a magnitude and phase- are you simply trying to extract that phase or the argument for each sample to have a phase versus time?